# unable to checkout or pull any branch on bitbucket nodejs

Tags: node.js, git, bitbucket

Using service account and nodejs i am pushing files on bitbucket repo.

I pushed a file with double quotes in the name and it got successfully pushed in master branch.

Now on my system, i am trying to take pull of master branch

```
error: invalid path '/en/data-"hello-begin-344.wav'
error: invalid path 'en/data-"If-your-cii-1710489359278.wav'
```

how can i fix this?

i don't have accessing deleting file from web portal, i have checked the documentation for rest apis, did not get the api to delete or rename the particular file